# Querying a specific line from a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following text file:
http://pastebin.com/K45Ew5CU

I would like to make a specific query which takes lines from a specific minute onwards and places them in a data grid which has an object (String TimeStamp, String ComputerName, String ID, String Event) as Its Data fields.

for example : Lets say I would like to display all the lines from 10:10:00 to this current time.

How do I test each line to see if it fits my time requirements?

Comment: What information do you have about the structure of the file? Are the fields tab separated?

Comment: Do you have made any attempt to solve your problem or are just waiting for someone to write a solution for you?

Comment: the fields tabs are separated each by 12 lines.

Comment: Im honestly clueless on how I even approach this query.

Comment: Don't bother parsing textfiles, use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` – in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
var queryResult = File.ReadAllLines("<yourFile.txt>").Skip(1).TakeWhile(x => (DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, 19), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds) > (new TimeSpan(10, 10, 0).TotalSeconds)).ToArray();
```

Now you can use the `queryResult` in your Data Table. If you need further help, leave a comment.

A better version, using anonymous types:

```
var queryResult = File.ReadAllLines("<yourFile.txt>")
                      .Skip(1)
                      .TakeWhile(x => (DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, 19), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds) > (new TimeSpan(10, 10, 0).TotalSeconds))
                      .Select(x => new { TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(x.Substring(0, 19), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), CoumputerName = x.Substring(21, 10), ID = x.Substring(45, 4), Event = x.Substring(59)})
                      .ToArray();
```

Now, you can access individual data from `queryResult`.

Comment: I would recommend using [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to avoid reading everything to memory at once. Then you don't need the `Split` either

Comment: @Patrick I know that method exists but I have experienced several problems with it.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I'm interested to hear what kind of problems you've seen. Might help others.

Comment: @Measuring To be honest, they were petty problems regarding line endings, and that cost me a lot of time and thinking to solve it. That's obviously a performance boost by using `ReadAllLines`. Added it in the post.